# FourSqaure API PushConsole

Tags: asp.net, foursquare

While I am trying to send test push i am getting below response

**Push Response**
Push sent!

**Response:**
Your Server returned: 500 Internal Server Error

And my code to receive push notification is as below

```
namespace FourSquareService
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX,    uncomment        the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class FourSquare : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string ReadFourSqurePush()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request != null)
            {
                return "Hello World";
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
     }
}
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a / at the end of the push url you provided in the app settings. I was getting the same error and that did the trick for me.